# trouble displaying image HSI converted to RGB python

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, matplotlib

I've been working in a algorithm to convert RGB to HSI and vice-versa in python 3, which it display the resulted images and each channel using matplotlib.

The trouble is displaying HSI to RGB resulted image: Each channel alone is being displayed correctly, but when it shows the tree channels together I get a weird image.

By the way, when I save the resulted image with OpenCV it shows the image correctly.

[Resulted display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZ5ht.png)

What I did, but nothing changed:

- Round the values and if it pass 1, give 1 to the pixel
- In the conversion HSI to RGB, instead define R, G and B arrays with zeros, define arrays with ones
- In the conversion RGB to HSI, change the values between [0,360],[0,1],[0,1] to values between [0,360],[0,255],[0,255] rounded or not
- Instead use Jupyter notebook, use collab.research by google or Spider
- Execute the code on terminal, but it gives me blank windows

**Function to display images:**

```
def show_images(T, cols=1):
  N = len(T)  
  fig = plt.figure()
  for i in range(N):
      a = fig.add_subplot(np.ceil(N/float(cols)), cols, i+1)
      try:
        img,title = T[i]
      except ValueError:
        img,title = T[i], "Image %d" % (i+1) 
      if(img.ndim == 2):
        plt.gray()
      plt.imshow(img)
      a.set_title(title)
      plt.xticks([0,img.shape[1]]), plt.yticks([0,img.shape[0]])
  fig.set_size_inches(np.array(fig.get_size_inches()) * N)
  plt.show()
```

Then the main function do this:

```
image = bgr_to_rgb(cv2.imread("rgb.png"))

img1 = rgb_to_hsi(image)
img2 = hsi_to_rgb(img1)

show_images([(image,"RGB"),
         (image[:,:,0],"Red"),
         (image[:,:,1],"Green"),
         (image[:,:,2],"Blue")], 4)
show_images([(img1,"RGB->HSI"),
         (img1[:,:,0],"Hue"),
         (img1[:,:,1],"Saturation"),
         (img1[:,:,2],"Intensity")], 4)
show_images([(img2,"HSI->RGB"),
         (img2[:,:,0],"Red"),
         (img2[:,:,1],"Green"),
         (img2[:,:,2],"Blue")], 4)
```

**Conversion RGB to HSI:**

```
def rgb_to_hsi(img):
  zmax = 255 # max value
  # values in [0,1]
  R = np.divide(img[:,:,0],zmax,dtype=np.float)
  G = np.divide(img[:,:,1],zmax,dtype=np.float)
  B = np.divide(img[:,:,2],zmax,dtype=np.float)

  # Hue, when R=G=B -> H=90
  a = (0.5)*np.add(np.subtract(R,G), np.subtract(R,B)) # (1/2)*[(R-G)+(R-B)]
  b = np.sqrt(np.add(np.power(np.subtract(R,G), 2) , np.multiply(np.subtract(R,B),np.subtract(G,B))))
  tetha = np.arccos( np.divide(a, b, out=np.zeros_like(a), where=b!=0) ) # when b = 0, division returns 0, so then tetha = 90
  H = (180/math.pi)*tetha # convert rad to degree
  H[B>G]=360-H[B>G]

  # saturation = 1 - 3*[min(R,G,B)]/(R+G+B), when R=G=B -> S=0
  a = 3*np.minimum(np.minimum(R,G),B) # 3*min(R,G,B)
  b = np.add(np.add(R,G),B) # (R+G+B)
  S = np.subtract(1, np.divide(a,b,out=np.ones_like(a),where=b!=0))

  # intensity = (1/3)*[R+G+B]
  I = (1/3)*np.add(np.add(R,G),B)

  return np.dstack((H, zmax*S, np.round(zmax*I))) # values between [0,360], [0,255] e [0,255]
```

**Conversion HSI to RGB:**

```
  def f1(I,S): # I(1-S)
    return np.multiply(I, np.subtract(1,S))
  def f2(I,S,H): # I[1+(ScosH/cos(60-H))]
    r = math.pi/180
    a = np.multiply(S, np.cos(r*H)) # ScosH
    b = np.cos(r*np.subtract(60,H)) # cos(60-H)
    return np.multiply(I, np.add(1, np.divide(a,b)) )
  def f3(I,C1,C2): # 3I-(C1+C2)
    return np.subtract(3*I, np.add(C1,C2))

  def hsi_to_rgb(img):
    zmax = 255 # max value
    # values between[0,360], [0,1] and [0,1]
    H = img[:,:,0]
    S = np.divide(img[:,:,1],zmax,dtype=np.float)
    I = np.divide(img[:,:,2],zmax,dtype=np.float)

    R,G,B = np.ones(H.shape),np.ones(H.shape),np.ones(H.shape) # values will be between [0,1]
    # for 0 <= H < 120
    B[(0<=H)&(H<120)] = f1(I[(0<=H)&(H<120)], S[(0<=H)&(H<120)])
    R[(0<=H)&(H<120)] = f2(I[(0<=H)&(H<120)], S[(0<=H)&(H<120)], H[(0<=H)&(H<120)])
    G[(0<=H)&(H<120)] = f3(I[(0<=H)&(H<120)], R[(0<=H)&(H<120)], B[(0<=H)&(H<120)])

    # for 120 <= H < 240
    H = np.subtract(H,120)
    R[(0<=H)&(H<120)] = f1(I[(0<=H)&(H<120)], S[(0<=H)&(H<120)])
    G[(0<=H)&(H<120)] = f2(I[(0<=H)&(H<120)], S[(0<=H)&(H<120)], H[(0<=H)&(H<120)])
    B[(0<=H)&(H<120)] = f3(I[(0<=H)&(H<120)], R[(0<=H)&(H<120)], G[(0<=H)&(H<120)])

    # for 240 <= H < 360
    H = np.subtract(H,120)
    G[(0<=H)&(H<120)] = f1(I[(0<=H)&(H<120)], S[(0<=H)&(H<120)])
    B[(0<=H)&(H<120)] = f2(I[(0<=H)&(H<120)], S[(0<=H)&(H<120)], H[(0<=H)&(H<120)])
    R[(0<=H)&(H<120)] = f3(I[(0<=H)&(H<120)], G[(0<=H)&(H<120)], B[(0<=H)&(H<120)])

    return np.dstack( ((zmax*R) , (zmax*G) , (zmax*B)) ) # values between [0,255]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [imshow documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) of matplotlib, you will see the following lines:

> **X** : array-like or PIL image The image data. Supported array shapes
>   are:
>
> (M, N): an image with scalar data. The data is visualized using a
>   colormap. (M, N, 3): an image with RGB values (float or uint8). (M, N,
>   4): an image with RGBA values (float or uint8), i.e. including
>   transparency. The first two dimensions (M, N) define the rows and
>   columns of the image.
>
> The RGB(A) values should be in the range [0 .. 1] for floats or [0 ..
>   255] for integers. Out-of-range values will be clipped to these
>   bounds.

Which tells you the ranges that it should be in... In your case, the HSI values go from 0-360 in the Hue which will be clipped to 255 any value above it. That is one of the reasons why OpenCV uses the Hue range from 0-180, to be able to fit it inside the range.

Then the HSI->RGB seems to return the image in float, then it will be clipped in 1.0.

This will happen only for the display, but also if you save the image it will be clipped most probably, maybe it gets saved as a 16 bit image.

Possible solutions:

- normalize the values from 0-1 or from 0-255 (this may change the min and max value) and then display it (dont forget to cast it to np.uint8).
- Create a range that is always inside the possible values.

This is for display or saving purposes... If you use 0-360 save it at least in 16 bits

Comment: Thanks @api55 ! I normalized the values to 0-255 and cast it to np.uint8, and it worked!

Comment: @kuro no problem, just beware that normalizing may give unexpected results if you use cv2.normalize with NORM_MINMAX. If you the scaling manually you may use always the same min and same max to avoid this unexpected behaviour :) BTW, if this solved your question you should accept the answer for people with similar problems to know that this solution worked